# When reading characters with fscanf - are spaces ignored?

Tags: c, character, scanf

I am reading a file of the following form:

```
c h a r a c t e r s
```

with fscanf:

```
fscanf(file, "%c", address);
```

in a loop. Will it read spaces as well? I want to ignore spaces. Should I use

```
fscanf(file, "%c ", address);
```

instead?
However, there is no space after the last character in line, so I'm thinking it wouldn't read the last char as it is not in "x " for but "x".

I cannot check because the program is not finished enough yet.

Comment: I would just use `fgetc` and test its result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the space in front of the format.

```
scanf(" %c", address)
```

The space really means "read **zero or more** whitespace", so `" %c"` means "ignore optional whitespace and read a character (necessarily not whitespace)".

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find that info any where.

Answer (score 0):

As you said add space to the string format but at the beginning of the string format `" %c"`

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt","r");
    char address;
    while(fscanf(file ," %c", &address)>0) {
        printf("_%c", address);
    }
    printf("_\n");
}
```